# Slim 4 assign twig parameters from middleware

Tags: php, twig, slim

I'm trying to upgrade my website's code from Slim v2 to v4. I'm not a hardcore programmer so I'm facing issues.
In Slim v2 I had some middleware where I was able to assign parameters to the Twig view before the route code executed.
Now I'm trying to manage the same with Slim v4 but without success.

I have a container:

```
$container = new \DI\Container();
```

I have the view:

```
$container->set('view', function(\Psr\Container\ContainerInterface $container) {
    return Twig::create(__DIR__ . '/views');
});
```

I try to use this from middleware:

```
$this->get('view')->offsetSet('fbloginurl', $loginUrl);
```

But nothing append when the view rendered.

If I try to use the same from the route inside, its working fine.

Example route:

```
$app->get('/', function ($request, $response, $args) {
   
    $params = array(...);
    return $this->get('view')->render($response, 'index.html', $params);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is a test code:

```
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface as RequestHandler;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;
use Slim\Views\Twig;
use Slim\Routing\RouteContext;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'config.php';
lib\Cookie::init();

$container = new \DI\Container();

$container->set('view', function($container) {
    return Twig::create(__DIR__ . '/views');
});

$container->set('flash', function ($container) {
    return new \Slim\Flash\Messages();
});

$container->get('view')->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('flash', $container->get('flash'));

AppFactory::setContainer($container);

$app = AppFactory::create();

$app->addErrorMiddleware(true, false, false);

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '...',
  'app_secret' => '...',
  'default_graph_version' => '...',
  ]);

$beforeMiddleware = function (Request $request, RequestHandler $handler) use ($fb) {
    $response = $handler->handle($request);
    if (!isset($_SESSION['fbuser'])) {
        $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
        $permissions = ['email'];
        $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('...', $permissions);
        $this->get('view')->offsetSet('fbloginurl', $loginUrl);       
    }
    else {
        $this->get('view')->offsetSet('fbuser', $_SESSION['fbuser']);
    }
    $uri = $request->getUri();

    $this->get('view')->offsetSet('currenturl', $uri);

    return $response;
};


$app->add($beforeMiddleware);

$app->get('/test', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
    $oViewParams = new \lib\ViewParams("home", "", "", "", "");
    $oProfession = new \models\Profession();
    $oBlogPost = new models\BlogPost();
    $oBlogTopic = new models\BlogTopic();
    $professions = $oProfession->getProfessionsWithLimit(14);
    $posts = $oBlogPost->getMainPagePosts();

    echo $this->get('view')->offsetGet('fbloginurl'); 
    $params = array('professions' => $professions,
        'posts' => $posts,
        'viewp' => $oViewParams->getMassParams());
    return $this->get('view')->render($response, 'index.html', $params);
});

$app->run();
```

When I use `echo $this->get('view')->offsetGet('fbloginurl');` within the middleware it shows up. When I use the same within the route there is nothing show up...

Comment: This was the answer: 
Isn't this ($handler->handle($request); where it calls the next level of the code, which is before you set anything. Try moving that line to the end of the $beforeMiddleware to see if it changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible failures. First, the DI container may always return a new instance, thus it doesn't store the variables in the correct instance and they are not rendered in the twig template. Second, you use a different approach in your route sample. You pass the variables via your `$params` variable and they are given into the template by this way.

So you may store `$this->get('view')` in a variable or pass the variables as the third parameter of `$params`.

**EDIT**: You could also check, if your variable in your DI\Container already exists and then just return the instance.

Comment: Using `Singleton` defeats the purpose of `DI`